# Conflito entre tabelas no sql servre 2012

Tags: sql-server

Estou com um problema ao fazer um relacionamento entre duas tabelas no sql server 2012. Como posso resolver isso?

Tabela 'tbl_chkrecebimento' salva com êxito
Tabela 'tbl_chkitens'
- Não é possível criar a relação 'FK_tbl_chkitens_tbl_chkrecebimento'.
A instrução ALTER TABLE conflitou com a restrição do FOREIGN KEY "FK_tbl_chkitens_tbl_chkrecebimento". O conflito ocorreu no banco de dados "USUARIOS", tabela "dbo.tbl_chkrecebimento", column 'ID_CKL'.

segue a imagem
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Que campos está a ligar na chave?

Comment: Vc esta correto eu quem não estou fazendo errado, como posso fazer o relacionamento correto ?

Comment: Como voce quer fazer o relacionamento? qual é a referencia?

Comment: Deve indicar qual a função das tabelas para determinar a sua relação (um para um, um para muitas, etc...) depois tem que indicar o tipo que colunas quer utilizar para esse relacionamento

Comment: A referencia e o campo ID_CHKLIST

Comment: A Tabela chkrecebimento e o cabeçalho, e a tabela chkitens são os itens referente a tabela chkrecebimento.

Comment: então a tabela chkrecebimento e um e a tabela chkitens são varios itens,

Comment: Bom dia.Ajustei minhas tabelas agora ja estou conseguindo fazer os relacionamentos. Obrigado